# Why does the grid_sample function limit the input values to [-1, 1]?

Tags: computer-vision, pytorch, opticalflow

The pytorch [doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.4.0/nn.functional.html?highlight=grid_sample#torch.nn.functional.grid_sample) says that "grid specifies the sampling pixel locations normalized by the input spatial dimensions. Therefore, it should have most values in the range of [-1, 1]". But why do they let `grid_sample` function specify the normalized pixel locations?

Comment: What you mean? Why have they done this way rather than using unnormalized pixel locations?

Comment: @Berriel Yes! Thank you for your clarification. That is exactly what I am confused with : )